# 'Querying' a data structure in Python based on a datetime

Tags: python

I need a data structure which can handle the following:

```
date_from (datetime)
date_to (datetime)
value (float)
```

...and I need to be able to 'query' this data structure based on a datetime (e.g. in pseudocode: `SELECT * FROM data_structure WHERE a_datetime >= date_from AND a_datetime <= date_to;`).

If there isn't a result from this 'query', I would need to be able to insert a new value into the data structure.

What's the best way of doing this? (I'm a bit stuck at the moment)

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more, hard to tell where is Python and where is a database involved

Comment: Sorry, yes, clarification being added... done.

Comment: How about a list with tuples: `[(datetime_1, object_1), (datetime_2, object_2), ..., (datetime_n, object_n)]` and filter based on the associated datetime?

Comment: @SimeonVisser I thought about that, but there may be gaps between one `date_to` and another `date_from`, so it unfortunately wouldn't work.

Comment: I think you're asking how to cache date-series information. If all dates are post 1st Jan 1970, you may benefit by caching your dates as [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for quick integer comparison. How many entries are in your dataset? May they overlap?

Comment: If you want to select data with a 'query', then why don't you use sqlite with these three columns, which returns a list of tuples with these three items? Maybe I'm understanding the question wrong, but could you explain this to me?

Comment: @MattH The entries don't overlap (they can be consecutive, though). Dates can't be guaranteed to be post-1st Jan 1970.  I'm mainly trying to do it this way to help lessen the load on the database - instead of querying the database, it would be querying this data structure where possible.

Comment: @johneth If you want to lessen the load on the database, wouldn't it be simpler to just copy the relevant table into memory: `con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")` and then copy the table with something like `ATTACH "old.db" as olddb'); CREATE TABLE bar AS SELECT * FROM olddb.foo'); 'DETACH olddb'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [SortedCollection Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/). It uses the [bisect module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) and lets you created a keyed collection. E.g.:

```
>>> from SortedCollection import SortedCollection
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> s = SortedCollection(key=itemgetter(0))
>>> s.insert((1,2,'a'))
>>> s.insert((10,20,'b'))
>>> s.insert((20,30,'c'))
>>> s.find_le(10)
(10, 20, 'b')
```

May help you create your cache of time period information, the bisect approach should let you access your date-keyed information efficiently.